# mod_rewrite add REQUEST_URI to URL-parameter, handle it with ColdFusion

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, coldfusion, jrun

I have a strange problem with mod_rewrite in combination with ColdFusion:

I'm using the following rewrite rules in my virtualhost-configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ index.cfm [L]

# Add trailing slash if missing
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?i)^[\\/]CFFileServlet
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.cfm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Clean up multiple slashes in URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]

# Pass all non physically existing files/folders to index.cfm in URL.original_url
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.cfm?original_url=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Everything is working fine except for one thing:

If I call `http://www.example.com/test/?asdf` my `URL.original_url` reads like this `original_url=/test/index.php&asdf` and I can't figure out why there is index.**php** in it.

I tried already leaving out the PT-flag but it doesn't work without it. All pages e.g. `http://www.example.com/test/` return `403 - Forbidden` and in title of the page says "JRun Servlet Error".

Thanks for any ideas on this one!

**EDIT:**
Ok, I missed something important: the folder `/test/` actually exists in my documentroot! Other URLs like `/test/does_not_exist/` are **not** affected by the described problem.

Summed up:

`http://www.example.com/test/` -> `URL.original_url` gets `/test/index.php`

`http://www.example.com/test/does_not_exist/` -> `URL.original_url` gets `/test/does_not_exist/` which is my expected behaviour.

Comment: I guess `index.php` is the first option in your `DirectoryIndex` so your /test/ is actually /test/index.php. Not sure how to avoid default document in the $1, though.

Comment: Seybsen - I don't think Sergii is right. wouldn't your rewrite rule preempt the default doc and write index.cfm in it's place? That's what the rule looks like to me. Perhaps there's an apache directive or something? I'm with you - I think it *aught* to go to index.cfm. Are you sure THIS rule set is loaded and not some other one?

Comment: @Sergii first value in `DirectoryIndex` is `index.html`.

Comment: @MarkAKruger I have double checked, if there are other RewriteRules or something like that in a .htaccess or in the virtualserver's config.